# Creating New Swift Package - Header Not Found

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-management, swift-package-manager

I've just created a new Objective-C library, and I'm trying to add support for Swift Package Manager.

The library itself is very basic. It has the following source structure.

```
ProjectName/ProjectName.h
ProjectName/ProjectName.m
ProjectName/Private/ProjectNameInternal.h
ProjectName/Private/ProjectNameInternal.m
```

The public source file imports the private header, and the private source file imports the public header. When I made a basic `Package.swift` and tried build it, it gave me the error that the private header cannot see the public one.

Is there a special way I'm supposed to declare all of these Objective-C headers?

([This is the library in question](https://github.com/timoliver/tosegmentedcontrol) if it helps.)

[image: Build Error]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to specifically add to your header search paths via cSettings. Ex:

```swift
.target(
    ...
    cSettings: [
    .headerSearchPath("ProjectName"),
    .headerSearchPath("ProjectName/Private"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hey Joe! Woah! Thanks for that! I tried it, and it cleaned up most of the issues, but it didn't solve the build issue occurring because I was importing a file that lives in the parent directory, inside the child directory. Maybe that's my more my bad organizing choices than a problem with SPM though. I'll keep playing with it, but this solution seems sufficient to me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. May not be an option but you could just keep the package file a level up and use the `path` parameter of target to operate as if you were in that directory. But obviously that's making a ton of assumptions about setup. :)

Comment: headerSearchPath is basically used to expose the header file in the same target, but it does not work if you have to expose that header file outside of the target. i.e if your framework is consumed by another framework in that case headerSearchPath is not working and you have to mentioned that in publicHeadersPath.